# how do I track how many users visit my website

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I just deployed my first ever web app and I am curious if there is an easy way to track every time someone visits my website, well I am sure there is but how?

Comment: what hosting? GoDaddy? WebFactional?

Comment: http://www.google.com/analytics/ ?

Comment: pythonanywhere, sorry its in the tag but i forgot to mention

Comment: [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) is another resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

know from myself people are obsessed with traffic, statistics, looking at other sites – tracking their stats and so on. And if there is enough demand, of course there are sites to satisfy You. I wanted to put those sites and tools in one list together, because at least for me this field was really unclear – I didn’t know what means Google Pagerank, Alexa, Compete, Technorati rankings and I could continue so on. I must say not always these stats are precise, but however they give at least overview, how popular the certain page is, how many visitors that sites gets – and if You compare those stats with Your site statistics, You can get pretty precise results then.

http://www.stuffedweb.com/3-tools-to-track-your-website-visitors/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/10-ways-how-to-track-site-traffic-popularity-statistics/

Comment: thanks, I was hoping it would be something as simple as a few lines of python code, I guess ill pass on this, I was curious but not that curious because at most, it will get like 5 hits from friends :D

Answer (score 5):

Easy as pie, use Google Analytics, you just have to include a tiny script in your app's pages

http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: thanks, I bookmarked this if I ever need it for a better project

Answer (score 5):

PythonAnywhere Dev here. You also have your access log. You can click through this from your web app tab. It shows you the raw data about your visitors. I would personally also use something like Google Analytics. However you don't need to do anything to be able to just see your raw visitor data. It's already there.

Comment: question about pythonanywhere. Sometimes I will update files and when I reload the web thing, it still doesnt reflect my changes? I even deleted my old css file and uploaded a new one, reloaded my page, and it still showed my old css file. Is this a bug?

Comment: It might be a slow update. But it is more likely that your browser is caching the static files. Chrome caches static files quite aggressively. Shift+Reload is your friend.

Comment: Yip, you're right: http://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1):

I am a huge fan of Cloudflare's analytics.  It is super easy to setup, and you don't have to worry about adding a javascript blurb to each page.  Cloudflare is also able to track all of the things that visit your page without loading the javascript.

http://www.cloudflare.com